# Checking for particular style using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

```
from docx import *
document = Document('ABC.docx')

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
 for run in paragraph.runs:
  if run.style == 'Strong':
   print run.text
```

This is the code I am using to open a docx file and to check if there is Bold text but I am not getting any result. If I remove the if statement , the entire file is printed without any formatting / styles. Can you please let me know how to identify text in particular style like Bold or Italics using python-docx ?
Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although *bold* and the style *Strong* appear the same when rendered, they use two different mechanisms. The first applies bold directly and the second applies a character style that can include any other number of font characteristics.

To identify all occurrences of text that *appears* bold, you may need to do both.

But to just find the text having bold applied you would do something like this:

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if run.bold:
            print run.text
```

Note there are ways this can miss text that appears bold, like text that appears in a paragraph whose font formatting is bold for the entire paragraph (Heading1 for example). But I think this is the property you were looking for.

Comment: Can you tell me how to identify Italics text ? Is there a generic documentation available for this ?

Comment: There's also a Run.italics property which operates similarly to .bold. The documentation has more on that here: http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/text.html#run-objects

Comment: @scanny do you know a way how to check for `'List Paragraph' == paragraph.style` for a given paragraph ? or any other style ?

Comment: ok, i figured it out i just need to use the name property on `_ParagraphStyle objects` so it is `'List Paragraph' == paragraph.style.name`

Answer (score 1):

To check for a **particular style** you could use the `name` property that is available in [`_ParagraphStyle objects`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style.html#docx.styles.style._ParagraphStyle) or [`_CharacterStyle objects`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style.html#characterstyle-objects)

example:

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if 'List Paragraph' == paragraph.style.name:
        print(paragraph.text)
```